# Asteroid position error after standard epoch change

Tags: pyephem

Recently, the MPCORB database changed its standard epoch. Then pyephem failed to calculate the position of asteroids.

Take Asteroid 2001 BP25 on 2015-11-23.55 UT as an example. With the old and new standard epochs, I calculated its position as follows:

```
import ephem
import datetime

tobs = ephem.Date( datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 23, 13, 12, 13) ) # observation time

obj = ephem.readdb( "2001 BP25 0,e,3.47304,134.76688,294.08950,2.4271529,0.26065039,0.2231376,330.92520,06/27.0/2015,2000,H 16.0,0.15" ) # old orbital elements
obj.compute( tobs )
print "With old orbital elements, ra = %.6f deg, dec = %.5f deg" % ( obj.a_ra, obj.a_dec )

obj = ephem.readdb( "2001 BP25 0,e,3.47303,134.76696,294.10956,2.4270882,0.26066081,0.2231111,23.04368,01/12.0/2016,2000,H 16.1,0.15" ) # new orbital elements
obj.compute( tobs )
print "With new orbital elements, ra = %.6f deg, dec = %.5f deg" % ( obj.a_ra, obj.a_dec )
```

Then I obtained the following output:

```
With old orbital elements, ra = 1.879871 deg, dec = 0.30927 deg
With new orbital elements, ra = 1.891992 deg, dec = 0.30874 deg
```

The online IAU MP checker confirmed the coordinates calculated with the old orbital elements.

Therefore, I am wondering: is there some constant in pyephem that should be changed for the new standard epoch?

Answer (score 0):

Happily, this issue was resolved, but I only just realized that the resolution had not been posted back here on Stack Overflow. It turns out that the translation routine that the Asker was using to convert the database into XEphem format was using a constant for the epoch, instead of using the epoch from the original file itself. Fixing the translation also resolved the difference in coordinates — the details were worked out here:

https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/issues/89